# Does agora/zoom have an API/SDK that would allow me to initiate a video call by clicking on a button and automatically ring a specific user

Tags: agora.io, zoom-sdk, agora-web-sdk-ng, agora-implementation, agora

Does agora/zoom have an API/SDK that would allow me to initiate a video call by clicking on a button and automatically ring a specific user. If yes can you provide sample code with steps to run it.

I tried searching documentation didn't find much details.